# Set <input type='checkbox'/> to 'checked' using a value from window.localStorage. (true or false)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Ultimately, the end goal is to have an input element set to checked or not checked on page refreshes, based on a value stored in local storage.

Let me start by sharing this is all coming from simple, html, css, and javascript files (jQuery).  No frameworks.

I am setting the value of 'sound' to either true or false, depending on user clicks on a slider button in my html:

```
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" id="toggle_sound">
            <span class="slider round" ></span>
        </label>
```

The javaScript (imported correctly) checks to see if the value 'sound' is set on page load and should return a boolean value:

```
// get value of sound bool from local storage
let soudBool = window.localStorage.getItem('sound');

// log value from local storage
console.log('sound value from window==>', soudBool);

// set value to button in dom
if (soudBool) {
  console.log('if else==> true');
  $('#toggle_sound')[0].checked = true;
} else {
  console.log('if else==> false');
  $('#toggle_sound')[0].checked = false;
}

$('#toggle_sound').change(function () {
  let button_toggle_value = $('#toggle_sound')[0].checked;
  console.log('checked button value real time ======>', button_toggle_value);
  window.localStorage.setItem('sound', button_toggle_value);
  const elems = document.querySelectorAll('audio');
  for (const el of elems) {
    el.muted = !button_toggle_value;
    // el.pause();
  }
});
```

Everything works as expected EXCEPT no matter what the value of 'sound' being set in local storage, the if else statement always goes to the same output and the checked button stays checked on p[age refreshes. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `localStorage.getItem` always returns a string, which either `"true"` or `"false"` in your case, but always a non-empty string. `if (soudBool)` is therefore always true, because only the empty string is falsy.